# How can I loop through the results of a select statement and trigger another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreach

sorry if my title is terrible, I couldnt figure out how to word it better.

I have the following:

```
  select @AMTrackid = AudioMediaTrackId from AudioMediaTrack where AudioMediaId = @Aid

  delete from AudioMediaTrackArtist where AudioMediaTrackId = @AMTrackid
```

At this point I want to delete from the AudioMediaTrackArtist for each @AMTrackid returned.

Now sure how I can do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from AudioMediaTrackArtist
where AudioMediaTrackId IN (
                            select AudioMediaTrackId 
                             from AudioMediaTrack 
                             where AudioMediaId = @Aid
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @M.Ali answer, `delete` statement have a `from` part which you can join table that you want to delete from, with any table.

so you can use this approach to delete record(s) in single delete statement

```
delete AudioMediaTrackArtist
    from AudioMediaTrackArtist join AudioMediaTrack 
        on AudioMediaTrackArtist.AudioMediaTrackId = AudioMediaTrack.AudioMediaTrackId
where AudioMediaTrack.AudioMediaId = @Aid
```